API Manager not offering the certificate in 8243 port
I have changed the default certificate wso2carbon of WSO2 with a new one matching the hostname of my WSO2, everything works fine, all the portals offer the certificate correct but when trying to access one API the certificate offered is the localhost one, not the new one as the portal do. Why is this happening? I added the certificate to wso2carbon jks and client truststore, and configured keystore tls, primary and internal with the new certificate in deployment toml.
This is the error that log the wso2carbonlog:

TID: [-1234] [api/am/devportal] [2024-11-14 10:42:37,939] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} - Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://IP:9711. org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://IP:9711.
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

As I said the WSO2 works fine it responds but the certificate offered is localhost: O=Default Company Ltd,L=Default City,C=XX and it returns an error.
Thanks

Is this a distributed setup or is it an all-in-one setup?

Is its AIO setup yes

Is it a active-active setup ?
